# Open telegram app from a link in a mobile web site

Tags: telegram

Is there any way to open telegram application from a website being in a mobile? I know if you use telegram:// you can open telegram app, but how can I open telegram and create a new conversation with a given number? i know it is possible by whatsapp like [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106145/whatsapp-link-with-phone-number-doesnt-open-whatsapps-web-app):

> this is the link https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=359883378007,
>   when the link loads it beign redirected to this link
>   whatsapp://send/?phone=359883378007

Answer (score 4):

You can use this link to open conversation with **telegram username**:

```
https://telegram.me/telegramUsername
```

#### telegramUsername:

username without @

Comment: yes it could be done but i like to know about the above question.

Answer (score 3):

To share with Telegram.me, you have the following URL options...

```
https://t.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
https://telegram.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
tg://msg_url?url={url}&text={text}
```

Take a look at the official API source: [Core.Telegram.org: Widgets -> Sharing Button](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share#custom-buttons).  They suggest the `t.me` format.  It seems like `telegramUsername` format, or any format indicating a user or a phone number, is *not supported according to the documentation*.

You may share:

- `url` : The URL you want to share.
- `text` : Text to accompany the URL you want to share.

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#telegramme

[image: Social Share URLs]

Answer (score 0):

**2022 Updates**

**YOU CAN'T DO THAT.**
But, you can do the same with username -

```
https://telegram.me/Telegram_Username_Here
```

For updating the information -
`telegram://` no longer works on the latest chrome browser of pc version, instead of this, use `tg://` which works great on all devices.