# Issue in sharing Firebase storage URL with Telegram

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-storage, telegram

I am trying to share a URL (Firebase storage bucket URL) from mobile website to Telegram app,

For example,
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxx/o/gs%2FBE24F9AE-8336-445B-8962-7BC4792C56B7.jpeg?alt=media

But, the above url is being converted as below which is not working. Because, the problem is %2F is being converted as / (by decoding). How to get rid of this?

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxx/o/gs/BE24F9AE-8336-445B-8962-7BC4792C56B7.jpeg?alt=media

Try pasting actual (first) url in browser is working. Then, the converted url by Telegram is not working.

**NOTE**: xxxxxxx is my firebase project name

Referred this ([Open telegram app from a link in a mobile web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966809/open-telegram-app-from-a-link-in-a-mobile-web-site)) for sharing link.

I need help here.

Code Snippet:

I m calling the below function during button click,

```
telegramOnClick = (episodeLink, episodeName) => {
    window.open(
        "tg://msg_url?url=" + encodeURIComponent(episodeLink) +
        "&text=" + episodeName, "_blank"
    );
  }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Most likely you'll need to escape the URL in your code, so that the existing `%2F` sequence remains intact. But without seeing that code it's impossible to say more.

Comment: How do you send the url to the user? As a hyperlink?

Comment: Update the question with code snippet